# Parcel error in actionbarsherlock

Tags: android-activity, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-view

I am getting a crash with below crash log..i cannot reproduce it ...anyone with the knowledge why its happening?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.qz.XXXX/com.qz.XXXX.XXXXStartActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@410839c0: Unmarshalling unknown type code -38 at offset 1124
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5485)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@410839c0: Unmarshalling unknown type code -38 at offset 1124
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2037)
at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2260)
at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1692)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2027)
at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2231)
at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1232)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1728)
at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:957)
at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.onRestoreInstanceState(SherlockActivity.java:127)
at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:929)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1162)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2329)
```

Answer (score 1):

Steps to reproduce:

1. Enable developer option "Don't keep activities"
2. Run application
3. Start other package activity
4. Press back -> crash

I have fixed it this way:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

If you don't need to save an activity state, it is quite a good solution.